# Ubuntu 20.4 freezes Gnome session when I connect USB 3.0 HDD 1GB

Tags: gnome, usb, freeze, external-hdd

When I connect usb HDD 1GB into usb 3.0 port gnome session gives me notification that Backup volume is inserted and then Gnome gets completely frozen. Nothing works except moving mouse.
When I force remove cable after few seconds Gnome blinks like restart or X server crash and it works fine.

Same disk was working on same system like two weeks ago. It works now on another laptop with Win 10 and it works now on same laptop with Pendrive PopOS in try mode.

[image]